# Monitoring Ehcache statistics?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, jconsole, dynatrace

I am using `Ehcache caching with spring`  configuration. I need to monitor the `Ehcache` object in jconsole-mbeans or jvisualvm, but i don't see ehcache mbeans under jconsole.

> I have also mentioned `statistics="true` like below

..........

Answer (score 2):

You can try to enable it in the code.

```
CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getCacheManager("CacheName");
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ManagementService.registerMBeans(manager, mBeanServer, true, true, true, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to to register ehcache with managed beanserver also like below

```
    <bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
  </bean>

    <bean id="managementService"
        class="net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService"
        init-method="init"
        destroy-method="dispose">

        <constructor-arg ref="ehcache"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="mbeanServer"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="true"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="true"/>
        <constructor-arg index="4" value="true"/>
        <constructor-arg index="5" value="true"/>
 </bean>
```

Your already must be having below entry in spring config xml

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
     <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
    <property name="shared" value="true" />
</bean>
```